# How do you display an image when the user touches it and is hidden again when they are not longer touching it?

Tags: objective-c

I am creating an application and I am having trouble finding any information on how the attribute for the image is only displayed when the user hovers over the textbox and is hidden again when the user is no longer touching it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this. I'll give one possibility:

You can use a button and add 2 actions, one for

UIControlEventTouchDown

and one for

UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside

in the first one you show the image and in the second one you hide the image

Comment: Confused...  Can you be a little more specific??  Is this in the interface builder?